# Managing multiple personal Facebook accounts in Hootsuite

Tags: facebook, hootsuite

I don't have an extra personal account lying around somewhere to test. I know that it is possible to manage

- multiple Twitter accounts
- multiple Facebook pages

But, is it possible to manage multiple Facebook **personal** accounts?

Comment: I don't have multiple facebook accounts to test it either, but this [HootSuite vs. TweetDeck vs. Seesmic](http://news.yahoo.com/twitter-management-hootsuite-vs-tweetdeck-vs-seesmic-164500735.html) comparison does say you can have multiple Facebook accounts with HootSuite. It doesn't specify whether that's pages or personal accounts, but the same category says no for Seesmic which *does* allow you to manage multiple Facebook Pages.